# How to create a discord bot which adds blacklisted user or channel?

Tags: typescript, bots, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a discord bot where you can add a blacklisted user or channel. I want something like this for the command:
`r!blacklist <channel/category/user> "channelID"`
I am stuck. How would you do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "blacklist"?

Comment: @LilyO “blacklist” in this case means a couple of different things. A blacklisted channel/category is one where the bot will not respond to any commands, and a blacklisted user is one of whom the bot will not respond to commands from.

Answer (score 0):

how you could implement this is to check on msg what the channel was the parent id of that channel or the author and then you just return.

as for the blacklist you could use a record<string, string> as <channelID/categoryID/userID>, type

that way you can put them in the object see if they are in the blacklist then return

Answer (score 0):

You should add the blacklisted user or channel's ID in your database and check if it is on the blacklist for each message that arrived.
I don't know which database you use, but if you are using SQL, you should create tables called "blacklisted_channels" and "blacklisted_users". Using this blacklist command, you should add the ID of the channel/user to one of these tables which is appropriate.
And you should check if the user's ID or the channel's ID is in the table in the DB when a message came. I mean the message listener.